# Serverless is unable to find the handler in nestjs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy my NestJS project to AWS lambda with serverless framework, I followed [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless)

I created a file `serverless.ts` in `src` directory along with `main.ts` file.

When I run `sls offline`, it successfull runs and gives following output:

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Starting Offline at stage dev (us-east-1)

Offline [http for lambda] listening on http://localhost:3002
Function names exposed for local invocation by aws-sdk:
           * main: projectName-dev-main

   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                                        │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/                                         │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/main/invocations   │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/{proxy*}                                 │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/main/invocations   │
   │                                                                        │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Server ready: http://localhost:4000
```

But when I open the localhost URL `http://localhost:4000`, I get 502 Bad gateway and
following error.

```
ANY / (λ: main)
✖ Unhandled exception in handler 'main'.
✖ Error: Cannot find module 'main'
  Require stack:
  - /home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js
✖ Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'main'
  Require stack:
  - /home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js
      at _loadUserApp (/home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js:310:15)
      at async module.exports.load (/home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js:341:21)
      at async InProcessRunner.run (file:///home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:41:21)
      at async MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///home/my-PC/Desktop/projectName/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/worker-thread-runner/workerThreadHelper.js:25:14)
```

Here is code:

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Calcutta';
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

serverless.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let server: Handler;

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Handler> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.init();

  const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
}

export const handler: Handler = async (
  event: any,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback,
) => {
  server = server ?? (await bootstrap());
  return server(event, context, callback);
};
```

serverless.yaml

```yaml
service: myProject

useDotenv: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  # - serverless-plugin-optimize

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: us-east-1
  profile: default
  memorySize: 128
  stage: dev
  environment:
    TZ: ${env:TZ}

functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/main.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: '{proxy+}'

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
    httpPort: 4000
```

Comment: Because your handler is in serverless.ts, replace `dist/main.handler` with `dist/serverless.handler` in serverless.yaml

Comment: @AmanB But in dist folder there is only 1 file that is main.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the serverless.yaml

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!**'
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - dist/**
    - config/production.js
```